# Unreachable Statement in url

Tags: android, unreachable-statement

When I enter the database url, I got error Unreachable Statement

```
String url= "http://www.example.com/php.php";
```

This is my code:

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2,container,false);
            return view;


            String url= "http://www.example.com";

            warga = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.warga);
            LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            warga.setLayoutManager(llm);

            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            list_data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("response ", response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("warga");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return view;` code is not executed after `return`. That's all. `return` should be very last thing you do in your method. Nothing can be done after `return`
this is Java very-basics.

Comment: After running, i got error again. "You cannot start a load on a null Context" what does it mean? Sorry, i'm a beginner:(

Comment: @YulianaRahmahSolin, that's another question, which does not relate to this question

Answer (score 0):

Everything written after `return view` will not be executed.

You need to write your code before `return` statement.

Answer (score -1):

move this `return view;`  from the second line of method to the last line of method